# a c++ code can't be compiled, because ifstream is inaccessable

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, fstream, ifstream

```
    //**************************************************************************************************************
// FILE: a04.cpp
//**************************************************************************************************************
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "Sorter.hpp"
using namespace std;
// Write the function header for Merge ()
void Merge(int a[] , int b[],int c[], int n)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    while (i < n || j < n) {
        // Write the if-elseif-elseif-... statement in the body of the while loop
        if (i < n  && j < n && a<=b) {
                c = a;
                i++;
        }
        else if (i < n && j < n && a > b) {
            c =b;
            j++;
        }
        else if (i < n) {
            c = a;
            i++;
        }
        else {
            c =b;
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    } // end while
} // end function merge

void ReadList(ifstream fin, int a[], int n);

void ReadFile(int a[], int b[], int& n)
{
    ifstream fin ("ints-in.txt");
    ReadList(fin,a,n); // come back again different than the psuedo code
    ReadList(fin,b,n);
    fin.close();
} 


// Write the function header for ReadList()
void ReadList(ifstream fin, int a[], int n)
{
    n = 0;
    int number;
    // Implement the sentinel loop
    while (fin >> number && number != -1) {
        a[n] = number;
        n++; // come back again
    }
}


void WriteFile(int a[], int n)
{
    ofstream fout("ints-out.txt");
    // Write a vary loop where variable ivaries from 0 to n - 1. In the loop send a[i] and ' ' to fout.
    for (int i =0; i <= n-1; i++) {
        fout << a << ' '; // come back again.
    }
    fout << -1;
    fout.close();
}


int main()
{
// Define int arrays a,b, and c and int variable n.
int a[100], b[100], c[200];
int n;

// Call ReadFile () passing a,b, and n
ReadFile(a,b,n);

// Define and create a Sorter object named sorter
Sorter sorter;
// Call SelectionSort() on sorter to sort a into ascending order.
// Hint: to access the ASCENDING constant data member of the Sorter class you write Sorter::ASCENDING.
sorter.SelectionSort(a,100,Sorter::ASCENDING); //come back again here.

// Call BubbleSort () on sorter to sort b into ascending order
sorter.BubbleSort(b,100,Sorter::ASCENDING);
// Call Merge() passing a,b,c, and n
Merge(a,b,c,n);
// Call WriteFile () passing c and 2n
WriteFile(c,2*n);

return 0;
}
```

I don't know why it can't be compiled.

> Error 1   error C2248:
>   'std::basic_ifstream<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ifstream' : cannot access
>   private member declared in class
>   'std::basic_ifstream<_Elem,_Traits>'  c:\users\hisham\documents\visual
>   studio 2012\projects\homework4\a04.cpp    39  1   Homework4 Error 2   error
>   C2248: 'std::basic_ifstream<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ifstream' : cannot
>   access private member declared in class
>   'std::basic_ifstream<_Elem,_Traits>'  c:\users\hisham\documents\visual
>   studio 2012\projects\homework4\a04.cpp    40  1   Homework4   3   IntelliSense:
>   "std::basic_ifstream<_Elem, _Traits>::basic_ifstream(const
>   std::basic_ifstream<_Elem, _Traits>::_Myt &_Right) [with _Elem=char,
>   _Traits=std::char_traits]" (declared at line 827 of "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\fstream") is
>   inaccessible  c:\Users\Hisham\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\Homework4\a04.cpp   39  11  Homework4   4   IntelliSense:
>   "std::basic_ifstream<_Elem, _Traits>::basic_ifstream(const
>   std::basic_ifstream<_Elem, _Traits>::_Myt &_Right) [with _Elem=char,
>   _Traits=std::char_traits]" (declared at line 827 of "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\fstream") is
>   inaccessible  c:\Users\Hisham\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\Homework4\a04.cpp   40  11  Homework4

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The error doesn't say `ifstream` is inaccessible.  It says (in its own convoluted way) that the copy constructor is inaccessible, because it is declared private.  The problem is that you're passing `ifstream` by value, which tries to invoke the inaccessible copy constructor.

```
void ReadList(ifstream fin, int a[], int n)
```

Pass it by reference instead.

```
void ReadList(ifstream & fin, int a[], int n)
```

Answer (score 1):

iostreams are not copyable, so can't pass them by value.

Answer (score 1):

```
void ReadFile(int a[], int b[], int& n)
{
    ifstream fin ("ints-in.txt");
    ReadList(fin,a,n); // come back again different than the psuedo code
    ReadList(fin,b,n);
    fin.close();
} 

void ReadList(ifstream fin, int a[], int n)
```

You are attempting to pass a istream instance by copy.  You cannot do that - the copy constructors are marked private.

You need to declare your ReadList function as:

```
void ReadList(ifstream& fin, int a[], int n)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on this same code and I have something different in the Merge() function.

```
void Merge(int a[], int b[], int c[], int& n)
 {
   int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
   while (i < n || j < n) 
 {
    if (i < n && j < n && a[i] <= b[j])
     {c[k] = a[i];
    i++;}
    else if (i < n  && j < n && a[i] > b[j])
     {c[k] = b[j];
     j++;}
    else if (i < n)
    {c[k] = a[i];
    i++;}
     else
     {c[k] = b[j];
    j++;}
    k++;
      }
  }
```

I put the i, j, and k in the brackets. 
I'm not sure if this is correct or not, but I haven't had any error messages on that part.